# Syntax error in other file when adding a foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach

Here's the error i'm getting :

> syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)' in D:\User\Documents...\Controllers\DeviceController.php:68

It happens in this code :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Data\Campaign;
use App\Data\Device;
use App\Helpers\Database;
use App\Helpers\DateHelpers;
use App\Helpers\ProfileHelpers;
use App\Helpers\Utils;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DeviceController extends ApiController
{
    public function show($deviceId)
    {
        return Device::find($deviceId);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $deviceId)
    {
        $isAlertActive = filter_var($request->input('isAlertActive'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        $isAlertAfter5Pushes = filter_var($request->input('isAlertAfter5Pushes'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        $isAlertAfter10Pushes = filter_var($request->input('isAlertAfter10Pushes'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        $hasAtLeastOneSettingActive = $isAlertActive || $isAlertAfter5Pushes || $isAlertAfter10Pushes;

        $settings = [
            'is_alert' => $isAlertActive,
            'is_alert_after_5_pushes' => $isAlertAfter5Pushes,
            'is_alert_after_10_pushes' => $isAlertAfter10Pushes
        ];

        if ($isAlertActive) {
            $settings['alert_seuil'] = intval($request->input('alertThreshold'));
            $settings['alert_votemini'] = intval($request->input('minVoteCountBeforeAlert'));
        }

        if ($hasAtLeastOneSettingActive)
            $settings['next_alert_in_hours'] = intval($request->input('nextAlertInHours'));

        Device::where('id_device', $deviceId)
              ->update($settings);
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function putInLocation($sectionId, $locationName)
    {
        $section = Section::find($sectionId);
        if ($section && $section->area->id_client == $this->clientId) {
            Location::createLocation($sectionId, $locationName);
            return self::jsonSuccess();
        }
        else
            return self::jsonBadRequest();
    }

    public function delete($locationId)
    {
        $location = Location::find($locationId);
        if ($location && $location->section->area->id_client == $this->clientId) {
            $location->delete();
            return self::jsonSuccess();
        }
        else
            return self::jsonBadRequest();
    }
}
?>
```

I don't see any syntax error there, i checked the brackets multiple times but maybe i missed something ?

What's weird for me is that there is no syntax error until i add a foreach in another file (D:\User\Documents...\Views\Partials\areasettings.php). Here's the foreach :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0 v">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span></span>
        <select class="form-control" id="deviceSelect"> 
            <option selected disabled> <?php echo trans('areasettings.add_id_placeholder') ?> </option>
            <option> TEST </option>
            <?php 
            $devices = $db->fetchAll("select `id_device_mac` from `dashboard_demo.nao_device`");
            foreach ($devices as $device) {
                $idDevice = $device->id_device;
                $idDeviceMac = $device->id_device_mac;
                //echo "<option value=\"$idDevice\">$idDeviceMac</option>\n";
                <option value="<?= $device['id_device_mac'] ?>"><?= $device['id_device_mac'] ?></option>
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo trans('areasettings.add_id_placeholder') ?>" autocomplete="off"
            ng-model="newSectionName">-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for helping me !

EDIT : Changed the fetchAll with this line (laravel way) :

```
$devices = DB::table('dashboard_demo.nao_device')->select('id_device_mac')->get()
```

But i still get the same error.
I searched deeper in my logs and also found that devices is undefined apparently.

Comment: And line 68 is? I have run out of finger, so a little help please

Comment: Is your `$db->fetchAll` standard PDO as that does not submit and execute a query, it just processes all the resultset into an array from an executed query

Comment: Can you not close the PHP file by removing the ?> at the end of you DeviceController, then try again and show the error trace you get again?

Comment: Sorry i was gone for a while. Line 68 is the end of my file, which is the curly bracket just before the end php tag.

Comment: I removed the ?> and got the same error. Yes it's standard PDO, but i'm probably gonna edit it to do the Laravel way since i use this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks wrong, if you are using vanilla PDO.

```
$devices = $db->fetchAll("select `id_device_mac` from `dashboard_demo.nao_device`");
```

PDO::fetchAll does not execute a query, it just processes the resultset of an already executed query.

So something like this perhaps

```
$sql = 'select `id_device_mac` from `dashboard_demo.nao_device`';
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ( ! $result ) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo())
    exit;
}
while ($device = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

    $idDevice = $device->id_device;
    $idDeviceMac = $device->id_device_mac;
    echo "<option value='$idDevice'>$idDeviceMac</option>\n";

}
```

This way should show you if any errors happened in the query.

Also changed the content of the while loop. You were using an array notation in there but an objct notation when getting data from the `$device` variable above?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me. I tried it but i still throw the same error. I edited the first post, might help.

Comment: How do the 2 files relate to each other?

Comment: They both act on the same table in my database (the device table). One file is the controller for the devices and the other file uses various table to show different datas, and one of these table is the device table.

Comment: Have you set PDO to throw exceptions?

Comment: I made some other fixes for things I just noticed

Comment: I get the usual "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." error on my page so it did not print anything there. I think the whole thing actually comes from the fact that "devices" is undefined.

Comment: Well where ever you are printing that message print the PDO `errorInfo` instead. Then it will give you a pretty good idea whats wrong

Comment: Managed to find what was wrong using errorInfo + log errors. Turned out to be simple, i just missed a table and changed the way my foreach works with an echo, everything works good now. Thanks !